# How to make the focus remain on the same treeList node?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, treelistview

**Document structure**
Form_1:
- Panel1: - gridView;
- Panel2: - treeList;
- Panel3: - UserControl (depending on the selected tree node);

**Scenario_1:**
  - User. selects a row in the grid.
  - Code. Sends to the variable the "ID" value of the row that the focus is on in the gridView. (handled by the gridView event).
  - Code. By default, focus is placed on the node "Node_1" treeList (handled by the gridView event).

- User. selects a node in treeList.
  - in Panel3, a UserControl is displayed, which corresponds to the "ID" row from the gridView and the "ID" of the node from treeList (processed by the treeList event);

**Scenario_2:**
User. Moves focus only across the rows in the gridView,
and in treeList, the focus is always on the same node.
Problem: Panel3 displays user control "UserControl_1", which matches only for grid_1 "row_1".
How to make it happen:
- Panel1 --- Panel2 ----- Panel3
- "lines_1" - "Node_1" - "UserControl_1";
- "lines_2" - "Node_1" - "UserControl_2";
- "lines_3" - "Node_1" - "UserControl_3";

Question.
How to fix the problem "Scenario_2"?

```
 private void gridView1_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {                
        idParser = Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "ID"));                

        TreeListNode nodeFocus = treeList2.FindNodeByKeyID(20);
        treeList2.SetFocusedNode(nodeFocus);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return;        
    }
}


        private void treeList2_AfterFocusNode(object sender, NodeEventArgs e)
        {
            int idNode = Convert.ToInt32(e.Node.GetValue("ID")); // "ID" вбыранного узла

            switch (idNode)
            {
                case 20: 

                    pathToSettingsMain = maskPath + idParser.ToString() + ".xml";                                                                                               

                    f01startURLs = new F01StartURLs(pathToSettingsMain);
                    splitContainer2.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
                    splitContainer2.Panel2.Controls.Add(f01startURLs);

                    userControlCurent = f01startURLs;

                    break;

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your current UserControl in the gridView1_FocusedRowChanged event handler as well. If an end-user select a node in TreeList, the treeList2_AfterFocusNode event will be also raised and the current UserControl will be changed correspondingly.

Comment: I do not understand well.
Could you show a sample code.
If I understand you correctly, I made the code based on your words.
  See code. https://codeshare.io/anlQK4
**1.** Do I understand your proposal correctly?

Solution_2
I tried at the end of the `gridView1_FocusedRowChanged` event to force the call treeList2_AfterFocusNode (object sender, NodeEventArgs e)
But I do not know how to do it correctly.
**2.** How to forcefully call treeList2_AfterFocusNode (???, ???).
Will “Solution_2” work?

Comment: Could you help with this question?  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640542/how-to-hide-a-row-in-gridcontrol1-and-show-this-row-in-gridcontrol2-if-the-u)  Thank.

Comment: I have reviewed your code. It looks correct. Generally, you do not need to invoke the AfterFocusNode event. It is sufficient to move your code to a separate method and call this method in the gridView1_FocusedRowChanged and treeList2_AfterFocusNode event handlers. You already do this in your code you shared here.